# Access shared file in Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to regularly download a file that someone shared with me on **Dropbox**. 
I manage to list all **my** shared links through the **HTTP API** (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links) but this don't list the file I want.

I can't figure out what is the correct way to download through the API a file   that someone shared with me. Here below you can see the print screen on Dropbox where this files is, if it can help...

[image: Print Screen dropbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it sounds like you need to use the [/2/sharing/list_received_files](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_received_files) and [/2/sharing/list_received_files/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_received_files-continue) endpoints instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!!